# Does HTML5 supports replacing the context menu?

Tags: html, firefox, browser, menu, contextmenu

I know that you can add context menu items(currently only in Firefox) but can you replace the context menu entirely with items specified?

By that I mean that if I create a context menu with:

- Action 1
- Action 2

Then when opening the context menu **ONLY** those items would appear.

I also mean according to the HTML5 `menu` element specification and not current implementations.

Comment: Yes, you could in HTML4, but *don't*.

Comment: I am talking about HTML 5 "menu" element

Comment: @Shedokan - the HTML5 `<menu>` element exists for semantic purposes; it doesn't have any actual special functionality of its own; you'd still need to write Javascript code for it.

Comment: Look at the source code: https://bug617528.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=554309 there is no javascript involved(except for taking actions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, HTML5 doesn't and you can't. An important reason for having the menu element affect the context menu was to allow authors to be able to put operations on the context menu without disrupting all the facilities that are built into the browser and are important to the user. So allowing the web page author to remove the existing context menu options would defeat the point.

Comment: Why would it defeat the point if you can already(on most browsers) remove the context menu entirely? a way of creating a native one instead of making a fake HTML one would be a lot better.
Or if you are making a web-app and all of the items in the context menu are not usefull while using your app?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't HTML that supports this, but the browser.

Some browsers do indeed allow you to disable the context menu and activate something else on right click, but others don't.

It's been possible in most browsers for ages (certainly long before HTML5), but one or two browsers have never allowed it, on the grounds that you're interfering with the standard browser UI. (Opera was always the odd one out here)

For browsers that do support it, you need to use the `onmousedown` event, which will give you an event object that will tell you which mouse button was pressed.

Or you can use a jQuery plugin -- there seem to be a few of them around for this. Try [this one](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqueryContextMenu) or [this one](http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/).

Comment: -1 for wrong context menu type, I don't want to create a context menu I want the browser to create a native context menu using the HTML5 `menu` tag